# How to loop through axis elements in a series of subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, seaborn

I have a series of subplots created using `sns.FacetGrid`, and mapping with `sns.scatterplot`. It generates 13 subplots. The plotting part works perfectly and does not need to be changed.

I am aiming to add a diagonal line to each subplot.

The best method I have found so far employs the following:

```
h = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue="category", col="category_2", col_wrap=3)
h.map(sns.scatterplot, "x", "y", s=75, alpha=0.4)

# get axes
ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8, ax9, ax10, ax11, ax12, ax13 = h.axes

ax1.plot([-1, 6], [-1, 6], transform=ax1.transAxes, ls="--", c="k")
ax2.plot([-1, 6], [-1, 6], transform=ax2.transAxes, ls="--", c="k")
... 
ax13.plot([-1, 6], [-1, 6], transform=ax2.transAxes, ls="--", c="k")
```

This is a ***very*** basic question... what is the best way to iterate through each ax.plot so I do not have to copy and paste that line 13 times?

These methods below do not work, because in the first case axi is not defined and in the second the f-string makes it a string object which cannot plot.

```
for i in range(1,14):
    axi.plot([-1, 6], [-1, 6], transform=axi.transAxes, ls="--", c="k")
```

and

```
for i in range(1,14):
   ax = f"ax{i}"
   ax.plot([-1, 6], [-1, 6], transform=axi.transAxes, ls="--", c="k")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map.axes.flat` functionality:

```
for ax in h.axes.flat:
    ax.axline((0, 0), slope=.2, c=".2", ls="--", zorder=0)
```

And parameters for `axline` can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axline.html)

Comment: thank you so much this is a MUCH better implementation.